# Align row middle with UITableView middle

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` that should show a particular row in its middle when it is first displayed.  In `viewDidLoad`, I use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to achieve this:

```
// Center vertically on current row
let scrollIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: currentRow, inSection: 0)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(scrollIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: false)
```

This makes the top of the current row aligned with the middle of the table view meaning that the content of the row looks lower than it should be.  How can I make the **middle** of the row align with the middle of the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView so you can use:

```
scrollRectToVisible:<#(CGRect)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>
```

and calculate CGRect yourself, this way you have way more control than with using:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath
```